# Selecting all text in a table cell on focus in Svelte or JS

Tags: javascript, html-table, svelte

This is more of a JS and HTML question than svelte.

I want to select all the text in the field when the element gets focus. It works fine when the element is an **input** element but it does not work with **td**. How can I achieve this with **td** (no jQuery)?

```
<script>
    function handleFocus(e) {
        e.target.select();
    }
</script>

<input on:focus={handleFocus} value="Testing"/>
<td on:focus={handleFocus} contenteditable="true">Testing</td>
```

[Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/890734149c6b40bebeb536fd13437599?version=3.49.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a selection range.

```
<script>
function handleFocus(e) {
        e.target.select();
    }
    
    function tdFocus(e) {
        const el = e.target
        const range = document.createRange();
       range.selectNodeContents(el);
        const sel = window.getSelection();
       sel.removeAllRanges();
       sel.addRange(range);
    }
</script>

<input on:focus={handleFocus} value="Testing"/>
<td on:focus={tdFocus} contenteditable="true">Testing</td>
```

[Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9184fdca85564557b8b4c1cb41d0f010?version=3.49.0)